# Detect Environment details while running Angular application

Tags: angular, deployment, build, azure-pipelines, octopus-deploy

I have an angular application which is build and pushed to Octopus using VSTS Build pipeline. And from octopus, deploying to different environments.

Also I can not directly deploy into UAT ofcourse. SO first deploy into DEV and the same build to UAT and the same build from UAT to PRD.

So my issue is I have some values in my app.module.ts which are different in different environments. But since everywhere using the same build I cant make it different. So what I thought is Angular application has to understand which environment it is (dv1/dv2/st1/st2/prd) and thus switch the values.

Is that possible or how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

I had same requirement like you. I actually have **Dev > QA > Stag > Prod** and all environment will have one build only.

I achieved by having host.js file called in index.html that is responsible to tell me which environment my app is running currently. This host.js is called in index.html file.

Basically host.js will take URL and determine which environment it is with condition given.

**host.js**

```
var host = window.location.host;
var env = "";
if (host.indexOf('stag.myapp.com') >= 0) {
  env = "staging";
} else if (host.indexOf('qa.myapp.com') >= 0) {
  env = "qa";
} else if (host.indexOf('dev.myapp.com') >= 0) {
  env = "dev";
} else if (host.indexOf('myapp.com') >= 0) {
  env = "prod";
} else {
  //Not fall in any condition
  env = "dev";
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/host.js"></script>
```

Now get that env variable into your **app.component.ts** like below.

```
declare let env;
```

Comment: That sounds great.. Will try that friend.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share another method in Azure Devops.

You could try to use the [Replace Token Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

This task could use the pipeline variables to replace the token in the `app.module.ts` file.

Here is an example:

In `app.module.ts` file, you could set `#{variablename}#` as the variable value.

```
  providers: [
    { provide: ENVIRONMENTER, useValue: #{environment}# }
  ],
```

In VSTS Build, you could set the specific value.

[image]

Then you could use the Replace Token task to replace the value in `app.module.ts`.

For example:

```
- task: replacetokens@3
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: 'folderpath(contain target file)'
    targetFiles: '**/app.module.ts (file path)'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true
```

In the same build, you can change the variables according to the required environment. This method also supports changing multiple value at once.

Comment: But since I am using Octopus Deploy, how could its possible since environment details are in Octopus.

Comment: @SandeepThomas. Thanks for correcting me. This method needs to determine the environment  in the build step (similar to manual setting). If environmental information exists in Octopus, it does not apply. Sorry for not being able to help.